# google documents access to new charts services

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am creating a script with the Google Apps Script editor accessed from  http://script.google.com. I would like to use the newer chart services documented at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.  The example there includes the following lines:

[html> [head>
[!--Load the AJAX API--]

[script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"][/script]

[script type="text/javascript"]

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

(I have substitued [ and ] for <  and > to keep things visible.)

Now, since I am writing a script within the script editor, I am not starting with "html" in brackets.  If I enter the line:

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

into my script then try to run the script, I get the message:

ReferenceError: "google" is not defined.

How can I access the Visualization API from the google Apps Script Editor?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Charts API is currently not supported in Web Apps created using the HtmlService. It is something the team is working to enable in the coming months.